# Kivy-python: duplicate image on texture

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, kivy

I am developing app in python 3.6 with kivy.
I'd like to display an image saved as numpy array.
I wrote this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2

class Test(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        img = cv2.imread(r'./kulki.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        w, h = img.shape
        texture = Texture.create(size=(h, w))
        texture.blit_buffer(img.flatten(), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        w_img = Image(size=(w, h), texture=texture)
        self.add_widget(w_img)

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

and this is my output:

[image]

for this image:

[image]

Does anybody know why there are several of the same pictures instead of one? Anw why do I have to change dimensions in places (w,h) -> (h,w)?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are converting the image to grayscale when you read it, then your are using `rgb` for the `Texture` color format. If you make those two agree, then your code will work. For example, change:

```
texture.blit_buffer(img.flatten(), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
```

to:

```
texture.blit_buffer(img.flatten(), colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='ubyte')
```